# Trying to prove the inequality $P(h(X)≥a)≥(E[h(X)]−a)/(α − a)$ in probability and measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I've been struggling for hours. The full details of the question is,

For a function $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,\alpha]$ that is nonnegative and bounded and $0\leq a<\alpha$ show that,

$P(h(X)\geq a)\geq \frac{E\{h(x)\}-a}{\alpha-a}$

I'm currently doing my bachelor in mathematics and I'm halfway through a integral- and measure theory course and I'm just going through old assignments seeing if I can solve them during the christmas break.

What I have tried to do is find something similar to $P(h(X)\geq a)$ and using the theorem that $P(h(x)\geq a)\leq\frac{E\{h(x)\}}{a}$. Further I would apply that $P(A)=1-P(A^{\textbf{c}})$, so I could flip the inequality around when multiplying by one.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Do you know how to apply Markov's inequality?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I have edited the question. I hope it meets the standards now and yes I know how to use Markov's inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Observe that $0 \le h(X) \le \alpha$, so for any $a \in [0,\alpha)$, $-a \le h(X) - a \le \alpha - a$.  Use the monotonicity of the expectation to see that $E[h(X)] - a \le \alpha - a$.

What's missing is $P(h(X) \ge a) = E[1_{\{h(X) \ge a\}}]$.  Can you put this back to the previous inequality?

> In the first inequality, multiply both sides by the above indicator function to get  \begin{align} h(X) - a \le& (h(X) - a) 1_{\{h(X) \ge a\}} \le (\alpha - a) 1_{\{h(X) \ge a\}}. \end{align}  Then take the expectation to conclude.

Comment: Remarks: I encourage you to find better bounds for $h(X)$, since this applies for whatever $X$.  We aren't considering the particular features of the distribution, so the bound can't be tight.

Comment: Thanks for the swift assistance! I hadn't thought of $P(h(X)\leq a)=E[1_{\{h(X)\geq a\}}]$, but I will keep that in mind.